# Copy database (all objects) to other database every 5 seconds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-2013

I have two databases - a CRM database (Microsoft Dynamics crm) and a company database.

These two databases are different.

How to copy the company database (all objects) into CRM database every 5 seconds?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a **backup** on a schedule - or you can do a **replication** between two database servers - but you cannot *copy one database into another* - what exactly do you even mean by that??

Comment: In  database company will (insert.update,delete,select)  and in CRM database view data record.

Comment: every 5 seconds? good luck with that

Comment: I've never seen a more clear example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: mirroring or replication might allow you to do what you need

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest way to do this (and one of the easiest) is to use a method called log shipping. This can (on a schedule even every 5 minutes or so) copy the log file to another machine and from the shipped log file restore to the target data base. Please ignore geniuses that will claim it can be done every minute because it takes a little while to close the log backup file, move it and reapply but a 5-10 minute window is achievable.

You can also use mirroring,transactional replication, and other High Availability solutions but there is no easy way to keep two machines in sync.

Comment: I can't use from mirroring.please wite links web site sample codeproject , .....thnx

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to duplicate the data? Can;t you query the source system directly if they're on the same server?

Else this might point you in the right direction: [Keep two databases synchronized with timestamp / rowversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433632/keep-two-databases-synchronized-with-timestamp-rowversion)